# Extending a query with calculated value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a log table something like the example below. I have a query which will group by FK and colB to show the most recent entry for each fruit per FK. This query is listed below. I would like to extend this query if possible to calculate the time difference between the current max value I'm bringing back and the most recent entry for the respective grouping where the progress = 1/10. I can split the progress column into two separate columns if need be, but I'm not sure what I'm trying to achieve here is even possible. any pointers?

```
--My Table
FK|colA|colB|progress|timestamp
2|y|apple|2/10|2023-03-03 09:43:20
1|c|orange|3/10|2023-03-03 09:42:00
1|b|orange|2/10|2023-03-03 09:41:00
2|x|pineapple|1/10|2023-03-03 09:40:40
2|z|apple|1/10|2023-03-03 09:40:35
1|a|orange|1/10|2023-03-03 09:40:00
1|c|orange|3/10|2023-02-03 11:02:00
1|b|orange|2/10|2023-02-03 10:41:00
1|a|orange|1/10|2023-02-03 10:30:00
```

```
--Current Query
SELECT l.*
FROM log l,
(SELECT FK, ColB, MAX(TIMESTAMP) AS Timestamp
FROM log
GROUP BY FK, ColB DESC
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC) l1
where l.FK=l1.FK
             AND l.Timestamp=l1.Timestamp
             AND l.colB=l1.colB
ORDER BY l.FK, l.Timestamp DESC;
```

```
--Current Output
FK|colA|colB|progress|timestamp
1|c|orange|3/10|2023-03-03 09:42:00
2|x|pineapple|1/10|2023-03-03 09:40:40
2|y|apple|2/10|2023-03-03 09:43:20
```

```
--Desired Output
FK|colA|colB|progress|timestamp|Timetaken(HH:MM:SS)
1|c|orange|3/10|2023-03-03 09:42:00|00:02:00 (2023-03-03 09:42:00 - 2023-03-03 09:40:00)
2|x|pineapple|1/10|2023-03-03 09:40:40|00:00:00 (2023-03-03 09:40:40 - 2023-03-03 09:40:40)
2|y|apple|2/10|2023-03-03 09:43:20|00:02:45 (2023-03-03 09:43:20 - 2023-03-03 09:40:35)
```

Comment: Getting the timestamp for the most recent entry per group, where the progress is 1/10, will pretty much follow the logic for your current query with an additional filter. Then you need to join the two queries together a calculate the difference. Please use proper join syntax with on clause rather than the old syntax of joining in the where clause.

Comment: Interesting. I'm looking for other answer too. What I've done https://dbfiddle.uk/6cEJoNE8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8, you can use LEAD() to get your next line to compare:

Something like that :

```
SELECT 
K, 
ColB, 
MAX(TIMESTAMP) AS Timestamp,
LEAD(MAX(TIMESTAMP)) OVER w,
TIMEDIFF(LEAD(MAX(TIMESTAMP)) OVER w, MAX(TIMESTAMP)) as compare
FROM log
GROUP BY FK, ColB DESC
WINDOW w as (ORDER by TIMESTAMP)
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC;
```

Results with my data without K and ColB :

```
2020-01-28 14:25:00 2020-01-28 14:30:00 00:05:00
2020-01-28 14:30:00 2020-01-28 14:45:00 00:15:00
2020-01-28 14:45:00 2020-01-28 14:47:00 00:02:00
2020-01-28 14:47:00 2020-01-28 15:00:00 00:13:00
2020-01-28 15:00:00 2020-01-28 15:00:00 00:00:00
2020-01-28 15:00:00 2020-01-28 15:06:00 00:06:00
2020-01-28 15:06:00 2020-01-28 15:30:00 00:24:00
2020-01-28 15:30:00 2020-01-28 15:34:00 00:04:00
2020-01-28 15:34:00 2020-01-28 16:15:00 00:41:00
2020-01-28 16:15:00 2020-01-29 07:57:00 15:42:00
2020-01-29 07:57:00 2020-01-29 07:57:00 00:00:00
2020-01-29 07:57:00 2020-01-29 08:00:00 00:03:00
```